# How to translate error messages in Colander

Tags: python-3.x, colander

How can I translate the error messages from the [colander](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/) validators? The documentation just says that it's possible.

```
def valid_text(node, value):
        raise Invalid(node, u"Some error message")

class form(colander.MappingSchema):
    name = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String(), validator=valid_text)
```

I know that [deform](http://deform.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) does it already but I need to use **colander** on his own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this issue was already [addressed and fixed](https://github.com/Pylons/colander/pull/157), but it will be part of the next release. I've just added the changes from [commit f6be836](https://github.com/makinacorpus/colander/commit/f6be836f74b9f6d010a17acdc2b2ea3c58edeb0a) and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [API documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/api.html#module-colander), the `msg` argument to `Invalid` can be a *translation string* instance. Information on working with translation strings is [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/translationstring/en/latest/tstrings.html#using-the-translationstring-class).